# Using A Query string value in my AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

So I have followed this gudie from another stack question:

The steps to get this working are:

1. go to Resources -> Integration Request
2. click on the plus or edit icon next to templates dropdown (odd I know since the template field is already open and the button here looks greyed out)
3. Explicitly type application/json in the content-type field even though it shows a default (if you don't do this it will not save and will not give you an error message)
4. Put this in the input mapping { "name": "$input.params('name')" }
5. click on the check box next to the templates dropdown (I'm assuming this is what finally saves it)

I understand this however I don't understand how I can then use this parameter within my lambda function (Python)

I have tried input.name with no success.

Comment: i get this error when I run in in the API "errorMessage": "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute name

Comment: Could you please refer the question you are talking about? Also if you can show us your code, we can help you out as best we can.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew

Answer (score 0):

You can use query strings like this:

```
UserName = event["UserName"]
```

Here is an example with Python:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
import boto3
import json
import decimal

# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-1', endpoint_url="http://dynamodb.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com")
table = dynamodb.Table('TableUsers')

UserName =event["UserName"]
UserId = event["UserId"]
UserPassword=event["UserPassword"]

response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'UserName': UserName,
        'UserId': UserId,
        'UserPassword':UserPassword
    }
)
return "Register Successfully"
```