# How can I pass query parameters in AWS API Gateway GET request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a GET Method on a resource, linked to a Lambda function, and I'm trying to pass through some query parameters.

For example:

GET https://xyz.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/myresources?page=123

I would like `page` to be passed in to the lambda `event` variable

Comment: Look at the top voted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a method request parameter named "page"
2. Define a mapping template for appropriate MIME type to send the parameter in the request body to Lambda,

i.e. "application/json" =>

`{
"page" : "$input.params('page')"
...
}`