# Getting referrer domain/url with Proxy Lambda integration

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I understand that we can set mapping template for API Gateway with Lambda integration request. With this type of request integration, referrer url can be fetched as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892000/aws-api-gateway-pass-referrer-url)
But for Proxy Lambda integration, we do not have option to set mapping template.

Is there a way to get referrer url even if I have enabled Lambda Proxy integration? Can we still use initial request object inside Lambda function?

Comment: `proxy integration` *proxies* the request / response through and the API gateway do not do any *transformations* as with `lambda integration`... you'd have to take the request properties from your lambda handler...

Comment: Did you look in `event.headers['referer']` inside the Lambda function?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, event.headers['referer'] is not available with proxy setting.

Comment: `console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(event));` It *should* be there: 
    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format