# Error from cloudfront in serverless framework lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to deploy a simple Slack lambda api which uses the `@slack/client` library to remove members and pinned messages from a specific channel. The issue that I am running into is the function executes without a problem, and it is removing the channel members without a problem, but my Lambda function keeps returning:

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
...
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
...

{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

as the response body. When I check the logs using `sls logs -f api`, I dont see any errors there either. I see the console.log of my function successfully executing.

My `serverless.yml` is as follows:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  profile: serverless

functions:
  api:
    handler: handler.api
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          method: POST
          path: clean
```

And my api code, i have removed the unnecessary function codes as they are doing their work, is :

```
module.exports.api = async (event, context, callback) => {
  let channel = JSON.parse(event.body).ctf
  let id = await findChannelId(channel)
  removeMembersFromChannel(id[0]).then(() => {
    removePinsFromChannel(id[0]).then(() => {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: `Cleaned ${channel} ${id}`,
        }, null, 2),
      })
    })
  })
};
```

Things I have tried:

- returning the response instead of using the `callback`
- using promises and async await
- testing the function locally using `sls invoke local`
- most of my search shows that this could be a permission issue, but all the references are for s3 usage which is something i am not using.

#### Questions

- Why am I getting this error, and how I can resolve this?
- After referenceing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52240132/7402287) In the handler function, I am using `JSON.stringify`. Using the `serverless-framework`, how can i avoid using Lambda proxy integration?

Comment: I encountered a similar issue. Turns out my path to the handler had a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Please, add console.log for detailed logging via cloudwatch and use x-ray. Some typical problems with cloudfront:
- a lot of time to propagate to edge locations (maybe u need recreate your cdn)
- logs from lambda@edge locates in invoked region