# Serverless, API Rest, get body on Lambda POST

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a Lambda POST function, I'm sending a json body for testing as:

```
{
  "id": 3
}
```

But I don't know how to read that body on my code.

At first I had a GET API, I called that API with:

POST: https://XXX.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/getData/123
(Content-Type: application/json)

so in my code I had:

```
export const handler = async (
  event: { pathParameters: { ID: any } }
): Promise<any> => {
    console.log(event.pathParameters.ID) // 123
```

`serverless.yml` was:

```
functions:
  feelookup:
    handler: src/functions/getData.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /getData
          method: get
          cors: true
```

But now I don't know how to read the body on POST

Edit: I tried by `event.body` but it doesn't existe body.

Here I have console.logs of `event` and `args` (from `CloudWatch`):

```
export const handler = async (
  event: any,
  args: any,
): Promise<any> => {
  console.log('event', event);
  console.log('args: ', args);
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use JSON.parse(event.body).

Comment: Also check if your API gateway settings are correct. Particularly whether you have chose lambda proxy integration or not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648467/getting-json-body-in-aws-lambda-via-api-gateway

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have chosen lambda **proxy** integration or lambda integration in the api gateway.
2. Might need to use JSON.parse(event.body).