# AWS API Gateway with Lambda not seeing the body

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, httprequest, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function which works perfectly fine when executed directly. As it's just for testing at the moment, it only reads the request `body` and returns the value of one of the children in response:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const response = {
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": event.body.maxNumber
    };
    return response;
};
```

However, when I create an Api out of it using the AWS Api Gateway, there is a strange behavior happening. If the Lambda function contains the code above, the response body is just empty. However, if instead of a child (the `maxNumber` in this case), I change the response to return the entire request body, it does return it.
Anyhow, while the lambda function works fine in isolation, when behind the API Gateway it appears it cannot see the children of the request body.

I have created both HTTP and REST apis, both with and without the proxy enabled, and no luck. Also cannot find any documentation specifically sampling something like my case (request body).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you are using REST Api with Proxy, we need to parse it first `JSON.parse(event.body)` because input body will be sent to lambda as string. then access its attributes.

Comment: Tried that already. It's not that :(

Comment: Enable lambda-proxy for your api gateway, then get body via `JSON.parse(event.body)`

Comment: I think similar question already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648467/getting-json-body-in-aws-lambda-via-api-gateway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For API Gateway proxy response, the body should be a string.

First, you need to parse the request body to get the JSON object and inside response, you need to stringify the response body as mentioned below :

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

const response = {
        "isBase64Encoded": false,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": JSON.stringify(body.maxNumber)
    };
    return response;
```