# Python can't read body in API Gateway request?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, rest, aws-lambda

I'm trying to code a Lambda function that is invoked via a hit to an API Gateway endpoint. Simply returning the event, I can see that there is a body in the response:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return str(event)
```

Response:

```
{
    'version': '2.0',
    'routeKey': 'ANY /identify',
    'rawPath': '/default/identify',
    'rawQueryString': '',
    'headers':
    {
       ...
    },
    'requestContext':
    {
       ...
    },
    'body': '<base64 encoded string is here>',
    'isBase64Encoded': True
}
```

However, as soon as I try to return *just* the body, I get the following error (multiple examples included which all return the same error).

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return str(event['body'])
```

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return json.loads(event['body'])
```

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    params = parse_qs(event["body"])
```

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return event['body']
```

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'body'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "requestId": "5acbcc66-da05-429f-baa9-6c8d83801b4f",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    return json.loads(event['body'])\n"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be relevant: [amazon web services - Getting json body in aws Lambda via API gateway - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41648467/getting-json-body-in-aws-lambda-via-api-gateway)

Comment: `<base64 encoded string is here>` are you even decoding the base64? What is the outcome of the decoding procedure?

Comment: Try this to check the available keys:
`print(event.keys())`

Answer (score 1):

`KeyError` indicates that you're trying to access a key in a Python dictionary that doesn't exist.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event): "API Gateway invokes your function with an event that contains a JSON representation of the HTTP request."

I think that what is happening is when you're returning `str(event)` it just returns the stringified version of the json event. But when you try to access `event[body]` in your handler without running `json.loads()` on the json first, you get the `KeyError` above instead. I typically run `json.loads()` first in all my handlers and then assign that to a `data` object (which is a Python dictionary) as below:

`data = json.loads(event["body"])`

Then I can use that body:

`print("[DEBUG] event['body']: {}".format(data))`