# Can't read query parameter in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am wanting to pass a query parameter from API Gateway into AWS Lambda but I am always receiving `null` values.

Here's my Lambda function which I merely want to return the value of http://foo.bar?**name=Dan**

```
'use strict';

exports.handle = (context, event, callback) => {
  callback(null, event.name);
}
```

In API Gateway I have done the following:

1. Create a Resource
2. Create a Method (`GET`)
3. Selected the correct Lambda function
4. Selected my GET method and clicked on `Integration Request`
5. Selected `Body Mapping Templates`
6. Set Content-Type to `application/json`
7. Added `{"name": "$input.params('name')" }`
8. Save and deploy!

However, when I load up my API the value of `event.name` is always `null`. Accessing the API is done via `...amazonaws.com/beta/user?name=dan`

Edit: I've tried the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew) but after simply returning the event in the callback, I only receive this data:

```
{
  "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": true,
  "logGroupName": "",
  "logStreamName": "",
  "functionName": "",
  "memoryLimitInMB": "",
  "functionVersion": "",
  "invokeid": "",
  "awsRequestId": "",
  "invokedFunctionArn": ""
}
```

I have omitted the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function arguments' placement for `context` and `event` are misplaced. Change their placement as below

```
'use strict';

exports.handle = (event, context, callback) => {
   callback(null, event.name);
}
```

Comment: Good spot mate :). Wanted to give 10 upvote but it allow only one :)

Answer (score 2):

Even I had the same issue before and I have modified body mapping template like below. Please try it out.

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{    
"name" : "$input.params('$.name')"
}
```

If you are using path parameter then please try below,

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
"name" : "$input.path('$.name')"
}
```

Comment: I still get a `null` value when using `event.name` in my callback function.

Comment: Are you using path parameter or query string?

Comment: I am trying to access the variable from a query string so /beta/user?name=Dan - I would like to access `name`

Comment: Can you please write a log for 'event' in Lambda? Just to see the data

Comment: I am not 100% sure what that means, I'm very new to AWS! If I use `callback(event)` then I get this response - https://qwjkvridyc.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/beta/user?name=foo

Comment: try callback(null,event) instead of callback(event) and share me result

Comment: I've added that in, the result remains the same.

Comment: After you modified the change I suggested did you deploy the API?

Comment: Yeah everything deployed, it's really bizarre! I didn't have any problems yesterday with such code. I am using Apex to push my Lambda functions, not sure if this has anything to do with it

Comment: Strange. Just to make sure is this because of current setup issue can you please make a sample API gateway and Lambda with the settings I have shared?

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help - The ordering of the params were wrong.