# API Gateway - validating request parameters

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

So, I've heard about request validator in API gateway.

Is it possible to validate request if it has atleast 1 parameter/querystring?

Example: Either name or id should be in the query string

https://something.domain.com/dev/employee?name=myname
https://something.domain.com/dev/employee?id=myid

Basically, what I want is that before a Lambda function is executed, this should consider these conditions first

- SHOULD have a parameter
- Either a name or an id should be in that parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a querystring or route parameter to AWS Lambda from Amazon API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew)

Comment: That one is more of "how to pass a parameter". My question is on "how to validate the request parameters"

Comment: Basically, what I want is that before a Lambda function is executed, this should consider these conditions first

- Should have a parameter

- Either a name or an ID should be in that parameter

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: I suggest looking at the answer by Vijayanath. API Gateway supports request validation prior to calling the Lambda function, however it only supports 'required' parameters. Hopefully you can re-design your API structure slightly to take advantage of the functionality that API Gateway supports.

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway can perform the basic validation. For the basic validation, API Gateway verifies either or both of the following conditions:

- The required request parameters in the URI, query string, and headers of an incoming request are included and non-blank.
- The applicable request payload adheres to the configured JSON-Schema request [model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-model.html) of the method.

To enable basic validation, you specify validation rules in a [request validator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/request-validator/), add the validator to the API's [map of request validators](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/request-validators/), and assign the validator to individual API methods.

Please read documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-method-request-validation.html)