# How to validate required parameters in request body using request validators in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API which needs to have following required parameters

```
{
    "Name":{"type":"string"},
    "Id":{"type":"string"},
}
```

It can also accept other parameters which may vary upon the user and I don't know their names or types.
Currently in API settings I have chosen Validate Body option in request validators but the problem is it throws 400 invalid request error if one sends extra parameters.

Is there a way to just verify the required parameters(pass through other parameters).I can also redesign the API structure if required.

The use case is that I don't want to invoke lambda function(configured as a webhook) in case required params are missing.

P.S. I have looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467838/api-gateway-validating-request-parameters) but haven't found the solution for my problem..Do not give solutions to use both query parameters and request body.