# Query String parameters from AWS API Gateway to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS Lambda function in Node that is triggered by a request to an API Gateway resource. In the Lambda, I am trying to retrieve the querystring parameters. Once all is set up correctly, I would expect them to be in the "event" object, right?

1. In my API Gateway resource, I click on the ANY method and then click **Method Request** and I provide some **URL Query String Parameters**
2. Then I go back and click on **Integration Request.** where I see another area called URL Query String Parameters. I provide the same parameter names there.
3. Then I go back and click **Test**. I see that I can provide values for the querystring parameter names that I entered. I provide the values and click Test.
4. In the output of my Lambda, I dump out the value of **event** and see that it is an empty object.

On [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/) I see some short documentation about **requestParameters**, but it doesn't tell me what to do with them, or how to access them in the Lambda.

I know that I can set up a **Body Mapping Template** on the **Integration Request** page and get it to work that way, but what is the purpose of the **URL QueryString Parameters** area on the Integration Request screen? Do those get passed to the Lambda? If not, where do they get passed to? What is their purpose? If you have a link to better documentation, please share.

Please don't just link me to this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew). I'm looking for more of an explanation specificically on how to use the URL QueryString Parameters specifically on the Integration Request screen in API Gateway.

Thanks! -- Anthony

Comment: Your life will be much easier if you use Lambda-Proxy integration.

Comment: @dashmug That makes sense, but I'm specifically trying to find out what the purpose of URL QueryString Parameters is for in the Integration Request page.