# How do I map path parameters from an API Gateway API to the Request Object of a Java Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda, written in Java, that accepts a Request Object of the structure

```
{
  "id": "be1c320a-144f-464d-b32c-38ec7fb4445b",
  "userId": "foobar"
}
```

When I call this Lambda through the test interface with such an object, it works fine.

I want to create an API where a `GET` request to

```
/users/foobar/items/be1c320a-144f-464d-b32c-38ec7fb4445b
```

i.e. of the form

```
/users/{userId}/items/{id}
```

calls this Lambda.

I have created the API resources `/users`, `{userId}`, `items`, and `{id}` appropriately.

And I have created the `GET` method (on `/users/{userId}/items/{id}`)and associated it to the lambda.

When I test the API, it invokes the lambda, but with null values in the request. I can see it package the `path` as `{"id":"be1c320a-144f-464d-b32c-38ec7fb4445b","userId": "foobar"}` in the logs, but that's not being sent in the body.

I have tried creating a template map (and have tried RTFM), but cannot see how to map path parameters to a body.

How do I achieve this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mapping template.

First, in the Method Request section, you should see `userId` and `id` as Request Paths

Then, in the Integration Request, do not choose Proxy Integration.

Then in the Mapping Templates section, add a new mapping template for `application/json` of the form

```
{
  "id"     : "$method.request.path.id",
  "userId" : "$method.request.path.user_id"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your Request Object structure may not be properly configured. There may be a few ways to configure this. Here is some information that has helped me.

[How to pass a querystring or route parameter to AWS Lambda from Amazon API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31329958/5787099) - Demonstrates this mapping (albeit with python). However, taking the top [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114185/5787099), if you enable "Use Lambda Proxy integration", you can similarily do this with Java as so:

```
@Override
public Object handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input, Context context) {

    Map<String, String> pathParameters = input.getPathParameters();
    String id = pathParameters.get("id");
    String userId = pathParameters.get("userId");

    // Handle rest of request..

}
```

This is a [tuturial using the serverless framework](https://serverless.com/blog/how-to-create-a-rest-api-in-java-using-dynamodb-and-serverless/#get-product-handler) to create an Api with Java. This tutorial similarily accesses the `pathParameters` by parsing the input rather than using the `APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent` java class.

```
@Override
public Object handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {

    try {
        // get the 'pathParameters' from input
        Map<String,String> pathParameters =  (Map<String,String>)input.get("pathParameters");
        String id = pathParameters.get("id");
        String userId = pathParameters.get("userId");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Error in retrieving product: " + ex);

    }
}
```