# How to pass nested query string parameter to AWS Lambda from Amazon API Gateway

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

In this question [How to pass a querystring or route parameter to AWS Lambda from Amazon API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew)

it shows how to map query string params to AWS lambda using API gateway. But, i want to pass a querystring inside a variable to lambda

For example:
/api/index&sample=index.php <--- I want this to store in 'url'

www.sample.com/prod?url=**/api/index&sample=index.php** <--- Like this

but 'url' only returns /api/index

sample=index.php is treated as another variable.

I used application/json on mapping templates

```
{
    "url": "$input.params('url')"
}
```

How do you do this. Please help thanks in advance

Comment: As a test, change the URL to `www.example.com/prod?url=/api/index%26sample=index.php` and see what you get.

Comment: By URL encoding it will escape the '&', but by any chance is it possible to treat it as a whole string? like "/api/index&sample=index.php" (this does not work of course)

Comment: I didn't realize you were familar with URL encoding.  Values in a query string that cause ambiguity or are forbidden are required to be escaped.  If I want to set the key `foo` to the value `bar&baz` in a query string, it's a violation of RFC-3986 to send it on the wire `foo=bar&baz` instead of as `foo=bar%26baz`... so your question, indirectly, is asking how to cause API Gateway to *incorrectly* tokenize the query string.  The problem, I would suggest, is that the client is not following the standards.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment of this RFC-3986 standards