# How to pass a path parameter in API gateway to invoke lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I need to pass a path param in the API.

By using the mapping template, I am able to pass query params and use them in the function.

Mapping template:

```
{
     "Id": "$input.params('Id')" //this works fine after passing params as <url>?param=vale
}
```

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew) I created the mapping template as following-

```
{
    "Id": "$input.params().querystring.get('Id')" // requirement is to be able to use <url>/value
}
```

I tried using 'Method request template' under genrate template, but it didn't work either.

When I invoke the URL urlname.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stag/functionname, it gives the value as undefined.

This is how I'm using the param:

```
class Lambda {
    static run(event, context, callback) {
      callback(null, 'Id '+ event.Id);
    }  
  }
  module.exports = Lambda;
```

Also, please tell me how to use those params in code. 
Be kind :)

Comment: Are you using `Lambda Proxy`?

Comment: @AssaelAzran I see answers related to that. Is it absolutely mandatory?

Comment: No. i just asked it to get more information. so i guess your api is a non proxy one. am i right?

Comment: Yes. I would prefer keeping it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to use `<url>/value` and get `value` from `event` follow this (Tested):

**Configure your API gateway resource**

[image]

[image]

Under **/api2/{id} - GET - Integration Request** configure your **Mapping Templates**

[image]

Execute request `https://123456.execute-api.my-region.amazonaws.com/stage/api2/123`

**Lambda**

```
console.log(event.id)
callback(null, {
    id:event.id
});
```

**CloudWatch**

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: how do we configure {id} under api?

Comment: just create a resource under api and in the path section insert {id}

Comment: added a snapshot to my answer. if you are using a non proxy api don't forget to configure status code in your `method response`.