# How to Implement Post Api Proxygateway Request Using C# Lambda Functions template

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am looking for solution I want to Implement the POST Api Gateway to Get functionality of AWS lambda functions
I have tried For Get Request and it works fine

```
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine("Get Again Request\n");
            var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
            { 
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = $"Hello Again AWS Serverless dd{request.QueryStringParameters["email"]}",
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
            };

            return response;
        }
```

But I want to try it for post Request when I change it to post from

```
          "RootGet": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/again",
              "Method": "POST"
            }
          }
        }
```

I get nothing in the query parameter
and then I tried to recieve object

```
public APIGatewayProxyResponse CustomPortalMessagingEmailForScheduleForm(EmailSendTemplate template,ILambdaContext context)
        {
         if (_sender.SendMail(template))
            {
                return new APIGatewayProxyResponse{
                   StatusCode=(int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                   Body="Sent Succssfully",
                };
            }
            return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = "Sent Succssfully",
            };
        }
```

It recieves null and 500 internal error thrown
How can I achieve this thing

Comment: CustomPortalMessagingEmailForScheduleForm is the name of your function handler?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew

Comment: @PrayagSagar yes it is the name of my function