# ERROR] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, crud

So I was trying to make a serverless API using `aws gateway`, `lambda` and `dyamodb` for a movie database. The post part of the api seems to work fine it's the get part that is not working. I get the followinng error on `postman` while testing:

got this error on the `postman` with error code `502`

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

My cloudwatch generated this error:

```
ERROR] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 32, in lambda_handler
    response = getMovie(event['queryStringParameters']['movie_id'])
```

My code snippet:

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
   logger.info(event)
   httpMethod=event['httpMethod']
   path=event['path']
if httpMethod==getMethod and path== healthPath:
    response=buildResponse(200)
elif httpMethod==getMethod and path == moviePath:
    response=getMovie(event['queryStringParameters']['movie_id'])
elif httpMethod==postMethod and path==moviePath:
    response=saveMovie(json.loads(event['body']))
elif httpMethod==patchMethod and path==moviePath:
    requestBody=json.loads(event['body'])
    response=modifyMovie(requestBody['movie_id'],requestBody['updateKey'],requestBody['updateValue'])
elif httpMethod==deleteMethod and path==moviePath:
    requestBody=json.loads(event['body'])
    response=deleteMovie(requestBody['movie_id'])
else:
    
    response=buildResponse(404,"Error Generated")
return response
```

Logger info says this:
[logger.info(event)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Akak.png)
Does anyone has a clue how to navigate out of this?
Thank you!

Comment: What does the line: `   logger.info(event)` output?

Comment: error may suggest that `event` is `None` or `event['queryStringParameters']` is `None`. You may have to use `if/else` to skip this part when you get `None` in variable.

Comment: you image shows `'queryStringParameters': None` and this makes problem. But I can't say why you have `None` in `queryStringParameters`

Comment: @RedCricket hey i used the .get method as you recommended and it basically raised an error that the query string parameters are none

Comment: Great! Next step is to figure out why that is.

Comment: @furas I did check with other operations as well it stays null only. As in the image the only part required is the 'movie _id' i the 'body' part of the json should i directly extract it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a querystring or route parameter to AWS Lambda from Amazon API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew)

Comment: @RedCricket Yes it somewhat does! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rewrite your code to use `event.get('...')`.  This will probably not correct your problem but it will make it easier to figure out what is wrong.

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
   logger.info(event)
   httpMethod = event.get('httpMethod')
   path = event.get('path')
   if httpMethod == getMethod and path == healthPath:
     response = buildResponse(200)
   elif httpMethod == getMethod and path == moviePath:
     params = event.get('queryStringParameters')
     if params is None:
         return buildResponse(400, "queryStringParameter is None!")
      
     movie_id = params.get('movie_id')
     if movie_id is None:
         return buildResponse(400, "movie_id is None!")


     ...
```